# Update progress with MRProgress

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I'm looking for help with trying to update a progress indicator using the MRProgress framework. I was able to set up the progress indicator, but I have no idea how to calculate and update its progress. I'm using CloudKit and trying to show the progress when saving a CKRecord. Could someone provide me some direction? Thanks in advance!

```
self.hud = [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.myCollectionView animated:YES];
self.hud.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeDeterminateCircular;
self.hud.titleLabelText = @"Uploading...";

// prepare the CKRecord and save it
[self.ckManager saveRecord:[self.ckManager createCKRecordForImage:self.imageDataAddedFromCamera] withCompletionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
      if (!error && record) {
             NSLog(@"INFO: Record saved successfully for recordID: %@", record.recordID.recordName);
             // need to get the recordID of the just saved record before adding the CID to the CIDArray
             self.imageDataAddedFromCamera.recordID = record.recordID.recordName;
             [self.imageLoadManager addCIDForNewUserImage:self.imageDataAddedFromCamera]; // update the model with the new image
             // update number of items since array set has increased from new photo taken
             self.numberOfItemsInSection = [self.imageLoadManager.imageDataArray count];
             //[MRProgressOverlayView dismissAllOverlaysForView:self.view animated:YES];
             [self.hud dismiss:YES];
             [self.hud removeFromSuperview];
      } else {
             NSLog(@"ERROR: Error saving record to cloud...%@", error.localizedDescription);
             [self alertWithTitle:@"Yikes!" andMessage:@"We encountered an issue trying to upload your photo to the cloud."];
            }
}];
```

Update: Converted cloudkit methods from convenience API to CKOperations in my CKManager class. I can see the progress updating through logging, but I don't see how to get it back to the viewcontroller. If I were to add it to the completion handler, wouldn't that only send it back once everything is completed? Here's my updated code...

CKManager.h
    - (void)saveRecord:(NSArray *)records withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *records))completionHandler;

CKManager.m
        - (void)saveRecord:(NSArray *)records withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))completionHandler {

```
NSLog(@"INFO: Entered saveRecord...");
CKModifyRecordsOperation *saveOperation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:records recordIDsToDelete:nil];

saveOperation.perRecordProgressBlock = ^(CKRecord *record, double progress) {
    if (progress <= 1) {
        NSLog(@"Save progress is: %f", progress);
    }
};

saveOperation.completionBlock = ^ {
    NSLog(@"Save operation completed!");
    completionHandler(records);
};

[self.publicDatabase addOperation:saveOperation];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show the progress of an operation, then you have to use the [CKModifyRecordsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKModifyRecordsOperation) and use perRecordProgressBlock method.

Comment: I assume you're talking specifically about this...


perRecordProgressBlock
 Property
The block to execute with progress information for an individual record.

Declaration
OBJECTIVE-C
@property(nonatomic, copy) void (^perRecordProgressBlock)( CKRecord *record, double progress)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Be aware that there is no guarantee that it's called. The documentation states: The operation object executes this block zero or more times for each record in the recordsToSave property.

Comment: So is there another way to get the status when uploading a CKRecord? Even a makeshift way?

Comment: Hmm... I thought there were 2 progress functions. Now I see there is only the perRecordProgressBlock. so I gues if you want progress you need to use that.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm going to do some refactoring today and try using that method.

Comment: The comment about zero or more times is because the progress callback won't be called in the case of an overall operation failure (no network connectivity, servers down, etc) or if the server rejects the save of the record and the upload never starts.

Comment: @Edwin Vermeer - Hey Edwin! I refactored my code as updated above but have a question about getting the progress reported back to the VC. Also, I was getting an error when trying to include in NSError in my callback/completion handler for this method. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: CloudKit callbacks are done on a background thread. So if you want to update your view, then you have to wrap that code in something like:                 NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { ...

Comment: I think for the error you could best use the: var perRecordCompletionBlock: ((CKRecord!, NSError!) -> Void)!

Comment: I got the error part working like you mentioned shortly after I posted the update. I'm not sure why it was throwing an error at first. Maybe I mistyped it initially. I'll play around with the NSOperation part to get the progress passed back to the view. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do I add that NSOperation code in my CKManager class which is called in the viewcontroller, or in the viewcontroller itself?

Comment: The logical place for the NSOperation code is the viewControler because that's the place where you will update your view.

Comment: I thought so, but wanted to make sure before proceeding. Thanks!

Comment: Do I have to NSOperation? Couldn't I just use GCD and update it by using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...? Also, regardless of the threading approach, I still don't see how I make the call from the VC to get the progress value from the saveOperation.perRecordProgressBlock in my CKManager class.

Comment: NSOperationQueue is just a 'convenience' mapper around dispatch_async. So you can use both. You could pass on an extra callback function to your method in the CKManager class. something like your own updateProgress block. As an alternative You could pass on your view controller to the CKManager class, but then you will have a tight coupling between those two. So the preferred way is a callback block

Comment: I had thought about your first suggestion the other day...using an extra callback function. But if I did that, wouldn't that be done in the completion handler and I would only get the final result, i.e. when progress = 1.0?

Comment: Ah, I just thought through that a little more. I could write a separate method in my CKManager class that uses a callback (i.e. updateProgress) and return the current progress value from the perRecordProgressBlock. Then on the main queue, I would call the updateProgress callback method from the VC. That's probably what you were saying in your last comment, correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what i meant. So the flow will be ViewController -> CKManager -> CKModifyRecordsOperation -> perRecordCompletionBlock -> yourOwnProgressCallbackBlock -> update view on main queue

Comment: Thanks! And Happy Easter to you!

Comment: I thought this would be pretty straight forward, but I can't figure it out. Here's what I'm having trouble with. I can't figure out exactly how to declare/define "myOwnProgressCallbackBlock". I do know that in the perRecordProgress block of the save operation is where I'll get the progress to be passed back in "myOwnProgressCallbackBlock". Also, I realized I have no idea when/where to call this in the VC to set the progress once I get this figured out. At the top of the thread you'll see where I'm calling this in the VC but where would I try to set the progress status there from this callback?

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment...in my CKManager class, here's what I declared as my progress callback method, but I'm not confident this is correct...
- (void)getRecordProgressWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(double progress))completionHandler;
I also created a property of type double in CKManager that is getting set to the progress value in perRecordProgress and the callback method would just send back that value.

Comment: don't set a property in the CKManager class. CloudKit code is async. You could start multiple operations that could run paralel. That property will then be filled by both operations. just call the callback function in the perRecordProgress block.

Comment: Can you create a new issue that include parts of your code? The maybe I can point out what to change.

Comment: I just created a new thread per your request - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473336/how-to-update-progress-with-ckmodifyrecordsoperation-perrecordprogressblock>
Thanks!!!